# Attempt to read property "name" on int - Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a Work model where one of the attribute is a requestor.

I'm trying to obtain the request data and I can obtain

- id
- user_id
- slug

but I'm try to `user_id->name`, and then laravel returns error with

> attempt to read property "name" on int

Controller:

```
$posts = Post::all();
return view('home', ['post' => $posts]);
```

View:

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($post as $item)
  <tr class="border-b dark:border-neutral-500">
     <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 font-medium">{{ $item->id}}</td>
     <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{{ $item->user_id->name}}</td>
     <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{{ $item->slug}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Work Model:

```
public function User()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: `$item->user_id->name`  is your issue. `user_id` is an int, and doesn't have relationships on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is explicit. The property `user_id` is an integer and not a relationship object, hence you cannot access the attribute on it.

To do so, while returning the posts include the user along with the posts.

Controller:

```
$posts = Post::with('user')->get();
return view('home', ['posts' => $posts]);
```

This is assuming you have a relationship with the `Post` and the `User` model.

Post Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and now you may access the attribute `name` from the `user` in your view like:

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($posts as $item)
<tr class="border-b dark:border-neutral-500">
    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4 font-medium">{{ $item->id }}</td>
    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{{ $item->user->name }}</td>
    <td class="whitespace-nowrap px-6 py-4">{{ $item->slug }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Documentation: [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Thanks you sir, my problem has solved, i'm miss match for view